# Cannot add view by right click in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I was working on creating sample app using ASP.NET Core using Visual studio 2015 update 3. I didn't see "add view" or "go to view" option when I right clicked on the action method. Is there any settings I need to change in visual studio?

[image]

Comment: I'm missing the same thing! There is a issue opened in github https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/806

Any news I will post an answer here

Comment: Thanks @mqueirozcorreia, looking forward for the answer. If I come across any , I will try to post the answer.

Comment: Did this get solved - still the case in VS 2017

Comment: Nope @niico, didn't find any solution yet, it is still open.

Comment: Did this get solved? @SravanDudyalu

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the difference between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core.

In the first one, you had two different types of controllers:

- View Controllers (inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`)
- Web API Controllers (inherit from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`)

So when you clicked on "Go to view" from that method

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio was smart enough to understand that the view `/Home/Index.cshtml` was the good one to navigate to.

With ASP.NET Core you don't have such difference anymore, all controllers inherit from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` no matter the controller returns a view or some raw data. And they can both return an `IActionResult` whatever the return type.

I believe Visual Studio could improve a bit and detects there is a line `return View();` in your method, but ASP.NET Core is new and there are tons of more important features with higher priority to implement for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Try to Delete that controller and then add View and also check Name of controller folder is correct